# Multiple Instances of ViewModel in Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I apologize if this has been asked before. I am trying to create multiple instances of the same type of viewmodel scoped to an activity using dagger-hilt, but even with different custom default args, it is returning the same instance each time.
I need all the viewmodel instances to be activity scoped, not fragment or navgraph scoped because I need all the fragments to subscribe to the updated data that will be received in the activity.

(Using Kotlin)

Activity Code

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class Activity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val vm1:MyViewModel by viewModels(extrasProducer = {
        val bundle = Bundle().apply {
            putString("ViewModelType", "vm1")
        }
        MutableCreationExtras(defaultViewModelCreationExtras).apply {
            set(DEFAULT_ARGS_KEY, bundle)
        }
    }) {
        MyViewModel.Factory
    }
    private val vm2:MyViewModel by viewModels(extrasProducer = {
        val bundle = Bundle().apply {
            putString("ViewModelType", "vm2")
        }
        MutableCreationExtras(defaultViewModelCreationExtras).apply {
            set(DEFAULT_ARGS_KEY, bundle)
        }
    }) {
        MyViewModel.Factory
    }
...

}
```

ViewModel Code

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    application: Application,
    private val myRepo: MyRepository,
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
...
    // Define ViewModel factory in a companion object
    companion object {
        val Factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory = object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            override fun <T : ViewModel> create(
                modelClass: Class<T>,
                extras: CreationExtras
            ): T {
                val defaultArgs = extras[DEFAULT_ARGS_KEY]
                println("extras $extras and default $defaultArgs")
                // Get the Application object from extras
                val application = checkNotNull(extras[APPLICATION_KEY])
                // Create a SavedStateHandle for this ViewModel from extras
                val savedStateHandle = extras.createSavedStateHandle()
                savedStateHandle.keys().forEach {
                    println("factory $it, ${savedStateHandle.get<Any>(it)}")
                }
                return MyViewModel(
                    application = application,
                    myRepo = MyRepository(application),
                    savedStateHandle = savedStateHandle
                ) as T

            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I print out the default arguments, the first initialized viewmodel is always returned, and is not initialized again even with both variables in the activity having different default arguments. Expected result: New viewmodel instance with different default arguments.

I think it has to do with the Viewmodel store owner key being the same, but I do want the viewmodel store owner to be the same, just as a new instance, if that makes sense.

I know that in the past you could use AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory, or a custom viewmodel factory with ViewModelProvider.get(), but I can't access ViewModelProvider.get without passing a ViewModelStoreOwner, and since I don't want to pass it to the factory since it could leak the activity, I'm confused as to how to go about this. Is there a better way than using hilt to create multiple instances of the same type of viewmodel in the same scope?

Answer (score 1):

```
override val viewModel: MyViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

Create instance of viewModel which lives with activity.